# php GD Libraries ; how to detect if the image have more white or black before crop to avoid artifact

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to detect if an image contains more white or more black...

I have a working croping function but when I want to crop an image (in some cases) the result have artifacts

Example 1 :

- Picture with more white ; [image]
- Give this reult when cropped [image]

Example 2 (ok) :

- Picture with more black : [image]
- give ok result : [image]

The code

```
$newImage300 = imagecreatetruecolor($jFinalWidth,$jFinalHeight);
$wcolor = imagecolorallocate($newImage300, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, $wcolor);
imagecopyresampled ($newImage300, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $jFinalWidth, $jFinalHeight, $jWidth, $jHeight);

// save image       
imagejpeg($newImage,__path_to_new_saved_img___,70);
```

What kind of code could be added to avoid the artifact from example 1 ?

Changing for grey it's worse...

See the results :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using another background for the target image, for example grey, to ensure you do not have the problem - even on the black image?

Comment: It makes it worse... now both have artifacts see the next answer

Comment: This is an example of how to mask an image automatically - http://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/backgroundMasking Detecting whether the background is black or white isn't covered by it.

Answer (score 0):

I did tryouts by changing `imagefill` by `imagecolortransparent` and voilà !

see the result
[image]
[image]

Working (fixed) code :

```
$newImage300 = imagecreatetruecolor($jFinalWidth,$jFinalHeight);
$wcolor = imagecolorallocate($newImage300, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($newImage, $wcolor);
imagecopyresampled ($newImage300, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $jFinalWidth, $jFinalHeight, $jWidth, $jHeight);

// save image       
imagejpeg($newImage,__path_to_new_saved_img___,70);
```